# Change detection is not working on disabled select

Tags: angular

I have two dropdown.On condition on the first dropdown i want to disable the second.But it is not working.So initiialy isTheFirstDropdownSelected booloean variable is true so the second dropdown is disabled,when the first dropdown is selected and it's function is called i am changing the isTheFirstDropdownSelected variable to true but the second select is still disabled.Where is my mistake

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="match-choosing-dropdown">
          <select id="dropdown-match-picker" [formControl]="control" (change)="navigateToSection('match-info-section')"
            (ngModelChange)="selectedMatchHandler($event)">
            <option *ngFor="let match of matches; let i = index" [ngValue]="match">{{match.home_team_name}} VS
              {{match.away_team_name}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
       </div>

       <div class="row">
        <div class="match-choosing-dropdown">
          <select [attr.disabled]="isTheFirstDropdownSelected" [formControl]="control" (change)="navigateToSection('match-info-section')"
            (ngModelChange)="selectedBetOptionHandler($event)" >
            <option>Select</option>
            <option *ngFor="let option of betOptionNames; let i = index" [ngValue]="option">{{option.name}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
       </div>


isTheFirstDropdownSelected = true;
 selectedMatchHandler(selectedMatch): void {
    this.isTheFirstDropdownSelected= false;
}
```

Comment: You have a mix of formcontrol and ngValue and ngValue on option instead of select. Can you try to make a stackblitz?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 selectedMatchHandler(selectedMatch): void {
    this.isTheFirstDropdownSelected= null; // assign null value 
}
```

--- if above doesn't work , then you are using reactive forms 
try using : reactive way to enable a field

```
 this.secondDropdownControlName.enable();
```

Comment: why should this work:  this.isTheFirstDropdownSelected= null;    and this not this.isTheFirstDropdownSelected= false;  ?

Comment: because  [attr.disabled]="isTheFirstDropdownSelected" -- when you have a value  either true false  ,  then disabled attribute will be there ,  
like disabled=true , disabled = false. (disabled don't care about value if it's there field will be disabled)

------
when we set  [attr.disabled]="null" -- null value , then that attribute is removed from that selector. (you can inspect) . that's  why i think it should work will null

Answer (score 0):

Example: two select boxes. If first model is empty (!selectedStatus), then the second box is disabled:

```
<select  [(ngModel)]="selectedStatus">
    <option value="">IBy Status</option>
    <option>Pending</option>
    <option>Paid</option>
  </select>
  <select  [disabled]="!selectedStatus" [(ngModel)]="selectedUser">
    <option value="" >By User</option>
    <option *ngFor="let user of allUsers" value="{{user.id}}">{{user.first_name}}  -             
       {{user.email}}</option>
</select>
```

See: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmodel-select-example-bjms94?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)